# Does nativescript supports .so file in android platform?

Tags: nativescript

Recently we are using nativescript to build an app, and we need to use a third-patty library which provides both IOS and Android SDK.
But it failed even we push .so file to lib folder, the error is the library cannot find the expected .so file during app running.
So I want to know does nativescript supports .so file and how to make it works?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can read more about this topic in [{N} google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nativescript/p8y2Y_Q4mpc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this task is not automated in the `tns` CLI but it should be possible to copy your `*.so` files in `<project>/platforms/android/libs/jni/armeabi-v7a` and/or `<project>/platforms/android/libs/jni/x86` directories. Gradle build respects these folders and `*.so` files will be included in the `*.apk` package.

Comment: Copying *.so files in the jni/arm64-v8a, jni/armeabi-v7a, jni/x86 folders worked for sometime. But, when I upgraded the tns core modules to the latest version, it stopped working. If I have the jni folder, the android app will crash without any errors at startup.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to push .so files and .jar files together, is to repackage them as an .aar file, using Android Studio. Then copy the wrapper .aar file to your nativescirpt platform/android/libs folder.

Here are the steps to package your SDK .jar and .so files into an aar file.

1. Create an application with blank activity in Android Studio.
2. Create a new wrapper module yoursdkwrapper (New->New Module->Android Library).
3. Copy your SDK .jar files to MyApplication\yoursdkwrapper\libs folder.
4. Under your MyApplication\yoursdkwrapper\src\main\ folder, create the following directory structure and copy .so files to each of architecture folders: jniLibs/arm64-v8a, jniLibs/armeabi, jniLibs/armeabi-v7a, jniLibs/x86.
5. yoursdkwrapper-debug.aar file will be generated in your MyApplication\epos2wrapper\build\outputs\aar.

Answer (score 0):

addition to for `Karthik Sankar`'s answer.
my *.so files got copied to app but did not get referenced.

In this case you need to manually reference all of them like this.

    `java.lang.System.loadLibrary("avcodec");`

to check if `*.so` files get copied use `Native Libs Monitor` app.

`ReLinker` might be helpful too

for detail https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/303