# nativescript android javacv not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nativescript, javacv

I successfully called simple android Activity with button from Nativescript. I exported aar and imported it as plugin.

Then i tried to call custom camera Activity from Nativescript.
this activity https://github.com/CrazyOrr/FFmpegRecorder

```
animationsFinished: function () {
    const intent = new android.content.Intent(com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), java.lang.Class.forName("com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"))
    intent.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.getInstance().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Activity opens with black camera and then gives me this error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.<clinit>(avcodec.java:1650)
```

It works without problem from android studio. But not working with `tns run android`

camera, external storage permissions are given and on for application

---

I did the trick from https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/133 : moved *.so files to "app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a" and "app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi" folders and it seems not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root problem was the library i was using was sdk22. 
https://github.com/CrazyOrr/FFmpegRecorder/issues/5

But answer for the question is have to manually copy `*.so` files
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/303

[Does nativescript supports .so file in android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737385/does-nativescript-supports-so-file-in-android-platform/40099408#40099408)