# How can i export this android application to aar library

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, aar

I want to use `FFmpegRecordActivity` from Nativescript. 
For that I have to export application to aar library and call `FFmpegRecordActivity` class from javascript via Intent.

I did that part editing `build.gradle` It worked.

But after `FFmpegRecordActivity` is displayed it breaks with this error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.<clinit>(avcodec.java:1650)
```

It seems not nativescript problem. Because same thing happened when i import aar from another android studio application.

camera, external storage permissions are given and on for application

---

I did the trick from https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/133 : moved *.so files to "app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a" and "app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi" folders and it seems not working

Comment: Solved with this
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root problem was the library i was using was sdk22. 
https://github.com/CrazyOrr/FFmpegRecorder/issues/5

But answer for the question is have to manually copy `*.so` files
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/303

[Does nativescript supports .so file in android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737385/does-nativescript-supports-so-file-in-android-platform/40099408#40099408)