# create a nativescript plugin for Android with compiled C files

Tags: android, plugins, nativescript

I'm trying to create a nativescript plugin, following the official documentation [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Android-Plugins-Infrastructure)

I created my .aar file and copied it into the `platforms/android` folder, which is working when I call my plugin class. The problem I'm facing is when I try to call a function that loads a native library, giving me a `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

I've already seen these links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737385/does-nativescript-supports-so-file-in-android-platform/40099408) [2](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2146) and tried all the options mentioned, but none of them seems to work. Since those links are two years old, I wonder if these methods are now deprecated.

My tns version is 4.1.2 and tns-android is 4.1.3.

I've tried adding the *.so files to the following folders:

```
platforms/android
platforms/android/libs
platforms/android/libs/armeabi
platforms/android/libs/jni
platforms/android/libs/jni/armeabi
platforms/android/armeabi
platforms/android/jni
platforms/android/jni/armeabi
platforms/android/jniLibs
platforms/android/jniLibs/armeabi
```

As you can see, I've tried all possible combinations based on the previous posts (my *.so files are for armeabi architecture)

Note that the only case that don't fail as the others is     `platforms/android/jniLibs/armeabi`. While trying this one I got an error telling me that one of the .so files is repeated (merge conflict) when calling `tns debug android`, the other ones just fail on runtime when I call the function

Answer (score 0):

I believe linker error is totally from your native library. Your call from plugin to native Java class is successful here, Java to C seems to be the issue.

Did you verify whether your native library (.so files) were compiled successfully, may be by importing them in a simple Android app? If it still fails, then it has nothing do with {N} runtime but may be something with NDK compilation.

Comment: my plugin comes from a sample project that shows me how to connect to a thrid party device. The sample project can load the library and works fine, but when I try to call a function inside the plugin from a class that loads one of those libraries it fails. So it seems like a NativeScript issue...

Comment: Is it a open source library? Do you have any sample hosted in Github?

Comment: I'm sorry, it is not open source  and I'm not allowed to share. Besides, I don't have the C files, just the compiled .so files

Comment: Are the *.so files exported with aar? Did you make sure your aar library is added to complied project, either by verifying the build logs / manually checking the ./platforms/android folder

Comment: my *.so files are indeed inside the generated .aar too. About checking platforms folder, my plugin is inside a platforms/tempPlugin folder but not as .aar

Comment: besides, when I check my plugin after adding it to a project, another .aar is generated. This one only contains the manifest, R and a BuildConfig.class file